# Leaking connection in JanusGraph/tinkerpop

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am connecting to janusGraph remotely via

```
cluster = Cluster.build()
                .addContactPoints(uri.split("\\|"))
                .port(port)
                .serializer(new GryoMessageSerializerV1d0(GryoMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance())))
                .maxConnectionPoolSize(poolSize)
                .maxContentLength(10000000)
                .create();
        gts = AnonymousTraversalSource
                .traversal()
                .withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
```

As gts is threadSafe, i keep gts in static context. Each thread usess the same object and none of the thread closes gts by calling gts.close()
Each thread runs query, for ex: 
`result = gts.V().has("foo","bar").valueMap().toList()`
I do not close either gts(graphTraversalSource) not graphTraversal object which is created by `gts.V()`

- Should I close each graphTraversal Object created out of
  gts(graphTraversalSource).?
- When should I close these objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `GraphTraversalSource`, the need to call `close()` is driven by the manner in which you construct the object (i.e. "gts" in your case). The javadocs on `DriverRemoteConnection` explain the requirements for `close()`. In your particular case, you pass the `Cluster` object that you constructed to `DriverRemoteConnection.using()` which implies that you wish to control the shutdown of the `Cluster` yourself and therefore calling `GraphTraversalSource.close()` will only close any `Client` instances that your `GraphTraversalSource` spawned to do its work. You would then be required to call `Cluster.close()` yourself to get a complete orderly shutdown and release of resources.

Behavior for `close()` on a `GraphTraversal` spawned from a `GraphTraversalSource`, is a bit different depending on whether or not you are remoting or not. In your case, you are using a remote traversal and therefore should call `close()` to release side-effects on the server (if the traversal generated any). Whether your server gathers side-effects or not for later retrieval is dependent on your implementation but for the most agnostic code it may be best to always explicitly do that. Note that traversals spawned over non-remote (embedded) graph databases that are iterated to completion, such that `hasNext()` is `false`, will trigger a call to `close()` and release resources held by the graph. For example, calling `iterate()` will trigger a `close()` automatically.

As a side note, support for collecting side-effects held on the server was removed from the TinkerPop protocol in 3.5.0 so that worry is going away - servers simply won't have side-effects held in memory anymore for later retrieval.